# Laravel - Undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having difficulty accessing a variable, when it's clearly there within the table.

The error falls on this line:

```
@if ($alert->alert_when == 1)
@endif
```

`Undefined variable: alert_when` - is the error.

I `dd()` the `get()` request prior to accessing the data in the view and I can see the variable it's retrieving:

```
["alert_when"]=> string(1) "1"
```

Full `dd` print screen:

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#521 (1) {
["items":protected]=> array(2)
{ [0]=> object(Criteria)#492 (20) { ["connection":protected]=> NULL
["table":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id"
["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true)
["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(15) {
["id"]=> string(2) "19" ["user_id"]=> string(2) "23"
["alert_when"]=> string(1) "1"
["created_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
["updated_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["deleted_at"]=> NULL }
```

I am able to access other data within the row, and there definitely isn't any typos!

Why is this error occurring? Many thanks in advance.

**Update**

`@if ($alert['alert_when'] == 1)` returns the correct response without errors. Why is this when I can access `$alert->name` like that?

Comment: So is `$alert` an object or an array? If the latter, you reference using `$alert['alert_when']`

Comment: I can access other data within the row using, for example, `{{ $alert->alert_name }}`. This works perfect.

Comment: Your dd output suggests that it is an array; but show the full output from dd to be certain

Comment: I've added it to the initial question @MarkBaker.

Answer (score 1):

Do a var_dump on the variable. You might be referencing it wrong. It could be an array.
You might have to reference it like this:

```
$alert[0]->alert_when
```